# How to pretty print the query results after calling fetch()?

Tags: jooq

I use `fetch()` and i get a `org.jooq.impl.ResultImpl` instance.
How to print them in nice way? Without me specifying the fields names(get the header from result)

Something like this :

```
+---+---+
| f1| f2|
+---+---+
|foo|  1|
|bar|  2|
+---+---+
```

I want something with header on top (even if a field name is duplicated), and the row results bellow.

I tried some methods from `ResultImpl` but i haven't found it yet.
`intoMap()` is nice but it complains when duplicate fields.
I also tried `intoList()` but this way i get only the values, without the field names.

I want both header and rows, like the `show()` method in Apache Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get this formatting is to just call `Result.toString()`. It calls through to `Result.format()` with a few sensible defaults for debugging. If you want to be in control of the formatting options, just call [`Result.format()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Formattable.html#format(org.jooq.TXTFormat)) yourself.

See also the [manual section about formatting text](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/exporting-text/).